# Or operator causing runtime error in iOS app with Metal

Tags: ios, metal

My iOS project compiles fine (no Xcode compilations errors in my .metal file), but I get a runtime error of `Compiler encountered an internal error`.  I have narrowed down the offending line to the following if statement in my .metal file:

```
if (X < 25 || X >= 75) {
     return 0;
}
```

Does Metal not support `||` operators?  Or am I just overlooking something?

Without that code, the program runs fine.

Comment: I don't think it's the OR operator. Are you sure you are returning the correct value type? Maybe your function expects a different type of return than an int.

Comment: The function requires an int, so that's not the issue.  I still don't know what's happening, but I kid you not, if I unroll the conditional into two, the code compiles without an error.

Comment: It's probably related to https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/48203, which appears to indicate that it's an Apple issue.

Comment: Maybe you should file a radar, however, in your question you are asking whether || is not supported. I can tell you for sure it's supported and you can see I used it multiple times, without any issue, here: http://mhorga.org/2016/05/10/using-metalkit-part-11.html

Comment: There isn't enough context here to know what's causing the problem, but any internal compiler error should be treated like a bug that's worthy of filing a Radar for. I'd also be happy to look into this further if you can provide the full shader source.